# can you pass an unresolved argument to a class function in python?

Tags: python, class

I tried to pass a parameter into a function inside a class, usually when I pass a parameter into a function I can use an unresolved attribute like so:

```
    def noodle(spices):
        print(f"noodle with {spices})
```

and depending on which spices I choose to enter when I'm using the function, that spice will be used in the print function like so:

```
    noodle(salt)
    noodle with salt
```

but when I try to do the same thing inside a class, pycharm tells me the argument "player" is unresolved and I can't seem to be able to do the exact same thing I otherwise would outside of the class, here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
    from turtle import Turtle



    class Paddle(Turtle):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.player1 = Turtle('square')
            self.create_paddle(self.player1)

        def create_paddle(self, player):
            self.player.penup()
            self.player.color('white')
            self.player.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=0.5)
```

I want to be able to create multiple paddles and reuse that function, but my method doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why

Comment: `player` is a parameter to `create_paddle()`, rather than an instance attribute, so you'd just refer to it as `player`.  No such thing as `self.player` has been assigned a value.

Comment: @jasonharper agreed _unless_ `player` shouldn't be an argument and `create_paddle` should instead refer to `self.player1`. In either case, an easy fix

Comment: i thought about it, but i implemented it wrong, after you said I removed the self. behind player

and it seems to work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, the solution was indeed very simple and it looks like that:

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Paddle(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player1 = Turtle('square')
        self.create_paddle(self.player1)

    def create_paddle(self, player):
        player.penup()
        player.color('white')
        player.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=0.5)
```